# how to save the information on the txt file

Tags: python, file

i am trying to make a perseon detection on an image but the aim is not to show the detected person on the image , the aim is saving the information of bounding boxes and confidence on a text file. So i write
these codes

```
info = open(r"output.txt","w")  
info.write(person_box) 
info.close
```

But it raised error which is `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray`.Also the complate code is at bellow.

```
def main():
    image = cv2.imread('resim.jpg')
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
    bilgi =[]

    (H, W) = image.shape[:2]

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 0.007843, (W, H), 127.5)

    detector.setInput(blob)
    person_detections = detector.forward()

    for i in np.arange(0, person_detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = person_detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence > 0.5:
            idx = int(person_detections[0, 0, i, 1])

            if CLASSES[idx] != "person":
                continue

            person_box = person_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = person_box.astype("int")
            
            info = open("output.txt","w")
            info.write(person_box)
            info.close
            
            print(person_box)
            print(round(confidence))

            #cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
main()
```

and when i write this `info.write(person_box,confidence)` it gives error again.
by the way beside this problem i have another problem how can i use more than one image and save their detection info on the txt file.I use these codes bellow but unfourtanetly it didnt work for me

```
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test\img'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3)]
```

above codes are outside of the `def main()`
the bellow codes were include the `def main()` i put it between two lines bellow.

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
        image = Image.open(image_path)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
We expect you to do your research before posting a question.

Comment: When you do post, please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You posted 40 lines of code for a 5-line problem.  Keep in mind the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1):

here's my suggestion its because your string to save a numpy array object, try to convert it as a string as such:

```py
preds_string = person_box.astype("int").tostring() # Convert to string

# or you can do as such
preds = np.append(person_box, confidence) # Add confidence to array
preds_string = preds.tostring() # Convert array to string

# To convert back to numpy array
bbox = np.fromstring(preds_string, dtype=int) # its important to add back the dtype if not the predictions look like this array([0.0e+000, 4.9e-324, 9.9e-324, 1.5e-323])
```